# C++ , Visual Studio 2019, error with classes, variables are non-standard syntax

Tags: c++, class

I am asking for help trying to finish this code, i need it to output information for two checking accounts after the initial balance has been diminished 5 times by 10 percent. I set up a for loop that i thought would be able to loop the instance method for newbalance but when i ran the loop successfully it printed out the 10% decrease 5 times instead of running the formula 5 times. When i attempt to print the data(such as the first name, lastname and new account balance) i get an error saying non-standard syntax, use & to create a pointer. Not sure how to fix this, this also is impacting the string variables for firstName and lastName.

```
include <string>
include <iostream>
include <cmath>
using namespace std;
class CheckingAccount {

public:
CheckingAccount(string, string, double);
void setbalance(double b) {
    balance = b; 
}

double getbalance() {
    return balance;
}
void setfirstName(string f) {
    firstName = f;
}
string getfirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
void setlastName(string l) {
    lastName = l;
}
string getlastName() {
    return lastName;
}

double newbalance() {
return(balance * .9);
}

private:
string firstName;
string lastName;
double balance;

};
CheckingAccount::CheckingAccount(string x, string y, double z) {
firstName = x;
lastName = y;
balance = z;
}

int main()
 {

CheckingAccount account1("Daniel", "Longo", 500);
CheckingAccount account2("Joe", "Mam", 750);

int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     account1.newbalance();
     account2.newbalance();
}
cout << account1.getfirstName << " " << account1.getlastName << " now 
has $"
    << account1.newbalance() << " in their account." << endl;
cout << account2.getfirstName << " " << account2.getlastName << " now 
has $"
    << account2.newbalance() << " in their account." << endl;
}
```

Any ideas on how to repair this problem would be much appreciated!

Comment: What line has the error?

Comment: `account1.getfirstName` -> `account1.getfirstName()`, same for `getLastName` and `account2`

Comment: `newbalance()` does not change the balance. Did you mean `double newbalance() { balance *= .9; return balance; }`?

Comment: Thank you Johnny Mopp and Yksisarvinen, both your suggestions fixed the code.